# Convert cv::Mat to Magick::Image

Tags: c++, opencv, imagemagick

I am attempting to convert an OpenCV C++ `cv::Mat` to an ImageMagick `Magick::Image`. The only examples I can find use the older, C OpenCV `iplImage` (see, for example, [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=18183)).

Is there a simple way of achieving this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

```
Image Mat2Magick(Mat& src)
{
   Image mgk(src.cols, src.rows, "BGR", CharPixel, (char *)src.data);
   return mgk;
}
```

Note that the function does not copy the data. If the magik image is released before you use the Mat image, result is `SEGFAULT`

Answer (score -1):

mat is always bigger then the image itself. The width is changed to multiple of 2 for sake of more efficient accessing the image data.