# How to process frames from a VGA2USB device using opencv c++?

Tags: c++, opencv, vga, frame-grab

Dear members of ***stack overflow***, hi:
I have just learned a little bit of **opencv** in **VC++**. Now, I faced a new problem:
I want to input my video frames from an **EPIPHAN VGA2USB** device. So, I installed the device **drivers**, downloaded its **SDK**, and opened one of its sample projects, named **V2U**, in **Microsoft Visual Studio 2010**. Using the **SDK Release Notes.pdf**, I added the line:

```
V2U_GrabFrame2* currFrame= FrmGrab_Frame(fg, V2U_GRABFRAME_FORMAT_RGB16, NULL);
```

to the `main` function of it (`fg` is a frame grabber object and `FrmGrab_Frame`, according to the **pdf**, returns a frame). The type `V2U_GrabFrame2` is defined as:

```
typedef struct ioctl_grabframe2 {
#define V2U_GrabFrame2_Fields(pointer) \
    pointer     pixbuf;     /* IN  should be filled by user process */\
    V2U_UINT32  pixbuflen;  /* IN  should be filled by user process */\
    V2U_UINT32  palette;    /* IN pixel format */\
    V2URect     crop;       /* IN/OUT cropping area; all zeros = full frame */\
    V2U_VideoMode mode;     /* OUT VGA mode */\
    V2U_UINT32  imagelen;   /* OUT size of the image stored in pixbuf */\
    V2U_INT32   retcode;    /* OUT return/error code */
    V2U_GrabFrame2_Fields(void*)
} V2U_PACKED V2U_GrabFrame2, V2UGrabFrame2;
```

in a header file. I may have to create a `cv::Mat` object from the info in `currFrame`, so that I can process it using **opencv** tools. Would anyone share a similar experience that can help a real beginner, please?!

Comment: Get the width, height and type (8/16 bit, RGB/BGR, greyscale) of your Epiphan image and create an OpenCV `Mat` of the same size. Work out how the pixels are organised in your Epiphan image and copy them across into the `data` pointer of the `Mat`. I expect it will be similar to this... http://stackoverflow.com/a/41847887/2836621

Comment: Or lookup the format of your Epiphan image buffer and add it to your question and see if some kind soul helps.

Comment: Dear Mark, thanks.

Comment: I did your second recommendation and am going to do the first one.

Comment: As you're clearly a beginner, it would help to experiment. You probably shouldn't aim to get the image directly from camera to OpenCV. Instead, write code to get the image from camera to .BMP file, and a second test to get from .BMP file to OpenCV. Finally, cut out the .BMP file in the middle. Why? So you can _see_ the image you're working on.

Comment: Dear MSalters, thanks.